# Android - Firebase Database accessing to sub directory

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my database in the firebase

```
{
  "Rooms" : {
    "room1" : {
      "Header" : {
        "Recipient" : "JZrMZeE6JXYULHRtDbksfagnQE53",
        "Sender" : "fD0E2IbeGub53n1muYSYX88N6US2"
      },
      "Message" : {
        "MESSAGE-QWEASD" : {
          "Message" : "Hello World",
          "Name" : "fD0E2IbeGub53n1muYSYX88N6US2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When i see the guide of firebase's database, it always requires a specified location to access data. However, I want to access sub directory(room1) of the main directory(Rooms) without indicating its name. For now, I need to indicate the name to access the data inside its name of room.

```
dataSnapshot.child("Rooms").child("room1").getValue().toString()
```

Is there a method that returns a string of sub directory's name

Comment: Is it to iterate through all children of a certain node?

Comment: You could use getChildren() but it will list all the immediate children of your "Rooms" node.

Comment: Yes, just found code : dataSnapshot.child("Rooms").getChildren().iterator().next().getKey().toString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access Rooms, you need to create Rooms object like your nodes above.
But I think you have room1, room2, room3 ... and your structure need to be like that (array list in object room to easy to parse as an Object Room). The key don't change.

```
{
  "Rooms" : [ 
    {
    "name" : "room1",
     {
      "Header" : {
        "Recipient" : "JZrMZeE6JXYULHRtDbksfagnQE53",
        "Sender" : "fD0E2IbeGub53n1muYSYX88N6US2"
      },
      "Message" : {
        "MESSAGE-QWEASD" : {
          "Message" : "Hello World",
          "Name" : "fD0E2IbeGub53n1muYSYX88N6US2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  {
       "name" : "room2",
       ....
  }
  ]
}

class Room {
    String name;
    Header Header;
    Message Message;
}

class Header {
    String Recipient;
    String Sender;
}
```

Do the similar with Message, but I think It needs to be easily to remove MESSAGE-QWEASD, only have Message and Name to make it easily as Object.

And finally

```
List<Room> rooms = (List<Room>)dataSnapshot.child("Rooms").getValue();
```

Comment: its not what I wanted, but its a good suggestion for me thank you